# How to remove Avada branding name from all over site the backend/dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

Avada branding/name is on the theme when you import the demo content. If you make your pages from scratch, you won't have Avada branding on your site. You can also edit your demo content to remove it.

Removing Avada name from the backend/dashboard won't be possible without editing the PHP code.

how to remove avada name from over all site?

Comment: You question is not clear. Please specify you use framework OR CMS if you use. Only tag is not proper way for that.

Comment: I'm using wordpress CMS

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress store mostly data into options table. I'm not aware with Avada create own db table OR use options table.

You need to check *Appearance > Theme Options > Footer* for copyright text. For more you need to check manually and remove it from theme options.

Let me know if there is any option which are not avail to remove from theme.

**Warning:** If you are using demo version of paid theme then please go to Avada forum for solution.